# How to get desired result in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In my application there is a table to store text and another table to store it's respective images..

My table structure goes as follows (`tbl_article`):

```
article_id | Page_ID | article_Content
-----------+---------+-----------------
      1    |    1    | hello world
      2    |    1    | hello world 2
```

where `article_id` is the pk and auto incremented.

Now in my other table (`tbl_img`):

```
image_id| image_location|article_id | page_id
--------+---------------+-----------+---------
    1   |   imgae locat |  1        |   1
    2   |  image loc2   |  2        |    1
```

where `image_id` is the pk and auto incremented.

In both table I am inserting data through table valued parameter, and in second table `article_id` is referencing `article_id` of the first table.

To get auto incremented column value I am using output clause:

```
DECLARE @TableOfIdentities TABLE 
        (
            IdentValue INT,
            PageId INT
        )

INSERT INTO tbl_article(page_id, article_content)
OUTPUT Inserted.article_id, @pageId INTO @TableOfIdentities (IdentValue, PageId)
    SELECT page_id, slogan_body_header 
    FROM @dtPageSlogan

INSERT INTO tbl_img(page_id, image_location) 
    SELECT page_id, image_location 
    FROM @dtPageImageContent
```

But now I have to insert values from `@TableOfIdentities` into `article_id` of `tbl_img` - how to do that?

Comment: Are you inserting only one article at a time? Can you post the structure of the two table variables dtPageSlogan and dtPageImageContent? They should contains some information that links each article with its images... that information should be used to create TableOfIdentities and join it with dtPageImageContent or you risk to assign all images to each article of the same page.

Comment: No I am passing multi article using Table valued param, here articles are stored in one tvp and their respective images on another tvp. Each article id should be insert in image table to show respective image..@Ezin82

Comment: You need to add a column on your tvp that links each image with its article.

Comment: @Ezin82 how to do that sir :D cant get you properly

Comment: Tomorrow I will post a solution :) You need an additional column , a temporary article id to link images and related articles properly. So you can use MERGE with OUTPUT, because with merge you can refer to columns from both the target and the source and build your TableOfIdentities tvp properly, then join it with dtPageImageContent to insert on tbl_img.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an additional column , a temporary article id generated from your code to link images and related articles properly. So you can use MERGE with OUTPUT, because with merge you can refer to columns from both the target and the source and build your TableOfIdentities tvp properly, then join it with dtPageImageContent to insert on tbl_img.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_article (
    article_id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY
    , Page_ID INT
    , article_Content NVARCHAR(MAX)
);

CREATE TABLE tbl_img (
    image_id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY
    , image_location VARCHAR(256)  
    , article_id INT
    , Page_ID INT
);

DECLARE @TableOfIdentities TABLE
        (
            IdentValue INT,
            PageId INT,
            tmp_article_id INT 
        );

DECLARE @dtPageSlogan TABLE(
        tmp_article_id INT -- generated in your code
    , page_id INT
    , slogan_body_header NVARCHAR(MAX)
);

DECLARE @dtPageImageContent TABLE (
        page_id INT
    , image_location VARCHAR(256) 
    , tmp_article_id INT -- needed to link each image to its article
)
    -- create sample data
INSERT INTO @dtPageSlogan(tmp_article_id, page_id, slogan_body_header)
VALUES (10, 1, 'hello world');
INSERT INTO @dtPageSlogan(tmp_article_id, page_id, slogan_body_header)
VALUES (20, 1, 'hello world 2');

INSERT INTO @dtPageImageContent(page_id, image_location, tmp_article_id)
VALUES (1, 'image loc1', 10);
INSERT INTO @dtPageImageContent(page_id, image_location, tmp_article_id)
VALUES (1, 'image loc2', 20);

-- use merge to insert tbl_article and populate @TableOfIdentities

MERGE INTO tbl_article
USING (
    SELECT ps.page_id, ps.slogan_body_header, ps.tmp_article_id 
    FROM @dtPageSlogan as ps
) AS D
ON 1 = 2
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT(page_id, article_content) VALUES (page_id, slogan_body_header)
OUTPUT Inserted.article_id, Inserted.page_id, D.tmp_article_id 
INTO @TableOfIdentities (IdentValue, PageId, tmp_article_id)
;

-- join using page_id and tmp_article_id fields
INSERT INTO tbl_img(page_id, image_location, article_id) 
    -- select the "IdentValue" from your table of identities
    SELECT pic.page_id, pic.image_location, toi.IdentValue
    FROM @dtPageImageContent pic
    -- join the "table of identities" on the common "page_id" column
    INNER JOIN @TableOfIdentities toi 
    ON pic.page_Id = toi.PageId AND pic.tmp_article_id = toi.tmp_article_id
;
```

[You can try it on fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ae3410/4)

Answer (score 0):

You need to **join** the `@dtPageImageContent` table variable with the `@TableOfIdentities` table variable on their common `page_id` to get those values:

```
-- add the third column "article_id" to your list of insert columns
INSERT INTO tbl_img(page_id, image_location, article_id) 
    -- select the "IdentValue" from your table of identities
    SELECT pic.page_id, pic.image_location, toi.IdentValue
    FROM @dtPageImageContent pic
    -- join the "table of identities" on the common "page_id" column
    INNER JOIN @TableOfIdentities toi ON pic.page_Id = toi.page_id
```

Comment: Not as I expect sir, please have a look : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a0cdd/3